# How to implement pagination when using amazon Dynamo DB in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use amazon Dynamo DB with rails.But I have not found a way to implement pagination.

I will use `AWS::Record::HashModel` as ORM.

This ORM supports limits like this:

```
People.limit(10).each {|person| ... }
```

But I could not figured out how to implement following MySql query in Dynamo DB.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM  `People` 
 LIMIT 1 , 30
```

Answer (score 50):

You issue queries using LIMIT. If the subset returned does not contain the full table, a `LastEvaluatedKey` value is returned.  You use this value as the `ExclusiveStartKey` in the next query. And so on...

From the [DynamoDB Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Pagination).

Comment: this answer is not taking into account that DynamoDB just provide pagination in one direction with mentioned `LastEvaluatedKey` and `ExclusiveStartKey`(going forward). Standard pagination with, at least, `previous` and `next` options is not possible out of the box with DynamoDB

Comment: @Srle, You provided yourself the way to have NEXT operation by using LastEvaluatedKey and ExclusiveStartKey. You can reverse the order of query and get PREVIOUS operation. That is available in DynamoDB out of the box.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev can you provide example,  gist or something with supporting both directions out of the box?

Comment: @Srle, "To reverse the order, set the ScanIndexForward parameter to false." from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html

Comment: Using `LastEvaluatedKey` is not "paging", it's "chunking".  Chunking is a _forward iterator_, paging is a _random access iterator_.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide 'page-size' in you query to set the result set size.
The response of DynamoDB contains 'LastEvaluatedKey' which will indicate the last key as per the page size. If response does't contain 'LastEvaluatedKey' it means there are no results left to fetch.
Use the 'LastEvaluatedKey' as 'ExclusiveStartKey' while fetching next time.

I hope this helps.

[DynamoDB Pagination](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination)

Comment: Using `LastEvaluatedKey` is not "paging", it's "chunking".  Chunking is a _forward iterator_, paging is a _random access iterator_.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple copy-paste-run proof of concept (Node.js) for stateless forward/reverse navigation with dynamodb. In summary; each response includes the navigation history, allowing user to explicitly and consistently request either the next or previous page (while next/prev params exist):

```
GET /accounts                -> first page
GET /accounts?next=A3r0ijKJ8 -> next page
GET /accounts?prev=R4tY69kUI -> previous page
```

Considerations:

1. If your ids are large and/or users might do a lot of navigation, then the potential size of the next/prev params might become too large.
2. Yes you do have to store the entire reverse path - if you only store the previous page marker (per some other answers) you will only be able to go back one page.
3. It won't handle changing pageSize midway, consider baking pageSize into the next/prev value.
4. base64 encode the next/prev values, and you could also encrypt.
5. Scans are inefficient, while this suited my current requirement it won't suit all!

```
// demo.js
const mockTable = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
const getPagedItems = (pageSize = 5, cursor = {}) => {

  // Parse cursor
  const keys = cursor.next || cursor.prev || [] // fwd first
  let key = keys[keys.length-1] || null // eg ddb's PK

  // Mock query (mimic dynamodb response)
  const Items = mockTable.slice(parseInt(key) || 0, pageSize+key)
  const LastEvaluatedKey = Items[Items.length-1] < mockTable.length 
                            ? Items[Items.length-1] : null

  // Build response
  const res = {items:Items}
  if (keys.length > 0) // add reverse nav keys (if any)
    res.prev = keys.slice(0, keys.length-1)
  if (LastEvaluatedKey) // add forward nav keys (if any)
    res.next = [...keys, LastEvaluatedKey]
  
  return res
}

// Run test ------------------------------------
const runTest = () => {
  const PAGE_SIZE = 6
  let x = {}, i = 0

  // Page to end
  while (i == 0 || x.next) {
    x = getPagedItems(PAGE_SIZE, {next:x.next})
    console.log(`Page ${++i}: `, x.items)
  }

  // Page back to start
  while (x.prev) {
    x = getPagedItems(PAGE_SIZE, {prev:x.prev})
    console.log(`Page ${--i}: `, x.items)
  }
}
runTest()
```

Comment: when you say, store entire reverse path, are you referring to the entire history that was queried from dynamodb? So for example, I click the next button 5 times, I get records with id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Now I have to store those numbers somewhere, so that if i click the back arrow 3 times, the frontend is aware of this list and will know which id to send?

Comment: Hi, yes, from memory that's how it has to work as ddb can only forward-scan (unless you perhaps had sequential keys and could guess the reverse order). 
As noted above, this might be inefficient for your application, but its been working great for mine since I posted, and I don't know yet of any other way you can do it...

Comment: I figured out a good way, using the clients side to hold the partition keys. What you would do is a scan on dynamodb. For my use case, I just need 1 record at a time. Once I get the record, I am creating an array on the client side with the partition key. Then, if the client hits the next result button, the next record in order is fetched, using the ExclusiveStartKey field. This partition key value gets added to the array on the frontend. If the user presses the go back button for the previous result, I look at the previous partition key in the array and perform a query call to dynamo.

Comment: Think of it like, viewing a PDF. 1 PDF at a time. I use dynamodb as a ledger system to mark where in S3 the file is stored. I do a look up to S3, then retrieve it from dynamodb. I'm able to create a dynamic array on the client side with each pdf that has been viewed (keeping track of the partition key). This way if the client needs to go back, the array contains a logical order of records that were fetched from dynamodb. Of course, if the user refreshes then this list is lost. This works for my usecase, but you could commit these values to a table for a stateful application.

Comment: What a shame, DynamoDB pretends to be "too fancy", but fails to deliver the basic functionality of a database out of the box. All the dirty work needs to be handled by a developer. We don't need this headache.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem.

The generic pagination approach is, use "start index" or "start page" and the "page length".

The "ExclusiveStartKey" and "LastEvaluatedKey" based approach is very DynamoDB specific.

I feel this DynamoDB specific implementation of pagination should be hidden from the API client/UI.

Also in case, the application is serverless, using service like Lambda, it will be not be possible to maintain the state on the server. The other side is the client implementation will become very complex.

I came with a different approach, which I think is generic ( and not specific to DynamoDB)

> When the API client specifies the start index, fetch all the keys from
>   the table and store it into an array.
>
> Find out the key for the start index from the array, which is
>   specified by the client.
>
> Make use of the ExclusiveStartKey and fetch the number of records, as
>   specified in the page length.
>
> If the start index parameter is not present, the above steps are not
>   needed, we don't need to specify the ExclusiveStartKey in the scan
>   operation.

This solution has some drawbacks -

> We will need to fetch all the keys when the user needs pagination with
>   start index.
>
> We will need additional memory to store the Ids and the indexes.
>   Additional database scan operations ( one or multiple to fetch the
>   keys )

But I feel this will be very easy approach for the clients, which are using our APIs. The backward scan will work seamlessly. If the user wants to see "nth" page, this will be possible.

Comment: This does not appear to be very scale-able, since it requires a table scan at the beginning.  If you have millions of records, for instance, you'll still need to scan the entire data-set, and then store all the keys in memory, losing a lot of usefulness that having a database gives you in the first place.  Not sure there's a good way to get the nth page in dynamodb at scale.

Answer (score -1):

In fact I faced the same problem and I noticed that `LastEvaluatedKey` and `ExclusiveStartKey` are not working well especially when using `Scan` So I solved Like this.

1. GET/?page_no=1&page_size=10  =====> first page
2. response will contain count of records and first 10 records
3. retry and increase number of page until all record come.

***Code is below***
***PS***: I am using python

```
first_index = ((page_no-1)*page_size)
second_index = (page_no*page_size)
if (second_index > len(response['Items'])):
    second_index = len(response['Items'])
return {
'statusCode': 200,
'count': response['Count'],
'response': response['Items'][first_index:second_index]
    
}
```