# Pagination in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement for to show the search result on the jsp with maxcount of 10 and it should have a pagination to traverse back and forward as pagination functionality.

Dynamodb has a **lastevaluatedkey**, but it doesn't help to go back to the previous page, though I can move to the next result set by the **lastevaluatedKey**.

Can anybody please help on this.

I am using Java SPRING and DynamoDB as the stack.

Thanks
Satya

Answer (score 6):

To enable forward/backward, all you need is to keep

`the first key`, which is `hash key + sort key` of the first record of the previously returned page (null if you are about to query the first page).

and

`the last key` of the retrieved page, which is `hash key + sort key` of the last record of the previously returned page

Then to navigate forward or backward, you need to pass in below parameters in the query request:

`Forward: last key as the ExclusiveStartKey, order = ascend`

`Backward: first key as the ExclusiveStartKey, order = descend`

I have achieved this in a project in 2016. DynamoDB might provide some similar convenient APIs now, but I'm not sure as I haven't checked DynamoDB for a long time.

Comment: Please check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Format your answer

Comment: Do you mind reminding me of your expectation? Is there anything in my answer difficult for you to understand due to the format? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. If you make code lines as code blocks it will be more readable it will more likely to get attention and upvotes and help other users too.

Answer (score 4):

Building on Ray's answer, here's what I did.  `sortId` is the sort key.

```
// query a page of items and create prev and next cursor
// cursor idea from this article: https://hackernoon.com/guys-were-doing-pagination-wrong-f6c18a91b232
async function queryCursor( cursor) {
  const cursor1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cursor));
  const pageResult = await queryPage( cursor1.params, cursor1.pageItems);

  const result = {
    Items: pageResult.Items,
    Count: pageResult.Count
  };

  if ( cursor.params.ScanIndexForward) {
    if (pageResult.LastEvaluatedKey) {
      result.nextCursor = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cursor));
      result.nextCursor.params.ExclusiveStartKey = pageResult.LastEvaluatedKey;
    }
    if ( cursor.params.ExclusiveStartKey) {
      result.prevCursor = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cursor));
      result.prevCursor.params.ScanIndexForward = !cursor.params.ScanIndexForward;
      result.prevCursor.params.ExclusiveStartKey.sortId = pageResult.Items[0].sortId;
    }
  } else {
    if (pageResult.LastEvaluatedKey) {
      result.prevCursor = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cursor));
      result.prevCursor.params.ExclusiveStartKey = pageResult.LastEvaluatedKey;
    }
    if ( cursor.params.ExclusiveStartKey) {
      result.nextCursor = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cursor));
      result.nextCursor.params.ScanIndexForward = !cursor.params.ScanIndexForward;
      result.nextCursor.params.ExclusiveStartKey.sortId = pageResult.Items[0].sortId;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to keep a record of the previous key in a session var, query string, or something similar you can access later, then execute the query using that key when you want to go backwards. Dynamo does not keep track of that for you.

Comment: +1 this; pass back your current `ExclusiveStartKey` you executed your query against in addition to your `LastEvaluatedKey` when they want to paginate backwards and your front-end will just request `ExclusiveStartKey` instead. There's no reason to inverse the sort order with `ScanIndexForward`

Answer (score 0):

For a simple stateless forward and reverse navigation with dynamodb check out my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64179187/93451.

In summary it returns the reverse navigation history in each response, allowing the user to explicitly move forward or back until either end.

```
GET /accounts                -> first page
GET /accounts?next=A3r0ijKJ8 -> next page
GET /accounts?prev=R4tY69kUI -> previous page
```